# What port is used by Java Web Start?

Tags: java, connection, firewall, java-web-start

May I know what port is used by Java Web Start? If I want to connect a Java Web Start client to a Java Web Start server, what port I need to open at the server side so that the client can connect to it?

I want to set up a firewall in the server machine but I don't know which port I should open.

Thanks.

Comment: See also http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/faq.html

Comment: Using SSL over the https port is one of the best options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java Web Start does not have a "Server" component. The most common setup is to host the files on a webserver. This is commonly hosted on port 80 (JWS however can use any file transport system supported by Java, such as UNCs or FTP).

Comment: Is it possible to host the web start application files on HTTPS port?

Comment: You can host the application using HTTPS just fine too.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that JNLP files are retrieved via HTTP by the webstart client, so there should be no special port handling required.

Comment: I'm surprised to know that... But, I need to key in username and password before I can download the web start application, if those information are sent using HTTP, can I say that it is not very secure? Because anyone with a packet sniffer will be able to see the username and password in clear text.